# Does paying a debt reset the clock on my Credit Report?

Tags: debt, debt-collection

I have a debt from 4 years back that is on my credit report. Because I have been out of the country for 4 years, I did not know about the debt until now.
My question is, does paying the debt reset the 7 year clock on my credit report, or will it just continue for 7 years from the original date?

I have no problem paying the debt (whether it is valid is a whole other story), but I do not want to fight with this for another 7 years.

Update: This is in California, the debt will be out of SOL by the end of January. But they have just called me (did not say i was here though).

Comment: Is it a medical bill, or not?

Comment: No phone bill from t-mobile